# PHP Mkdir will not work

Tags: php, mkdir

I have a simple script that all I need it to do is create a directory with the name of the GET variable. When I run this script, it doesn't seem to create the directory. I would like this directory to be in the same directory as the PHP file.

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
umask(000);
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$dir."/",0777);
```

Comment: What you are doing is incredibly dangerous.  As it stands right now, I can create directories anywhere on your server that the server has access to.  **Always** make sure when touching the file system that the resolved path (with `../` and what not) is where you expect it to be.  Don't let your users define any file names or anything like that.  Otherwise, you open yourself up to a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Put some error handling in there. Most of the time the error is self evident. The following snippet, lifted from PHP manual, shows you how.

```
$rs = @mkdir( $dirPath, 0777 ); 
if( $rs ) 
{ 

    // success

}else{ 

    // print error information 
    echo 'an error occurred. Attempting create folder'; 
    echo '<br>dirPath: ' . $dirPath; 
    echo '<br>php_errormsg: ' . $php_errormsg; 

}
```